# Iterate through NSManagedObjectContext objects?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to iterate through all of the objects in my NSManagedObjectContext, and update them manually. Then, every managed object should be updated.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: At the first time, many objects get created with wrong information. I need to manually fix that.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically you could iterate through all the entity descriptions in your managed object model, build a no-predicate fetch request for them, then loop over all the returned objects and do some update. Example:

```
// Given some NSManagedObjectContext *context
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[context persistentStoreCoordinator]
                               managedObjectModel];
for(NSEntityDescription *entity in [model entities]) {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    // Error-checking here...
    for(NSManagedObject *object in results) {
        // Do your updates here
    }
}
```

Note you can cast the NSManagedObjects returned as necessary either by testing for class equality (using `isKindOfClass:` or a related method) or by figuring out what class the current entity is (using the `managedObjectClassName` property on `entity` in conjunction with the `NSClassWithName()` method).

Comment: Casting is not necessary, all of the fetch methods and the -objectAtIndex: method return id. All of the properties in a NSManagedObject can be accessed via KVC and can be queried via -doesRespondToSelector:

Comment: True, but I tend to get frustrated with code that's littered with `doesRespondToSelector:` calls - casting, while not strictly necessary, can be a lot more readable down the road.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like a very heavy handed approach to the problem.  If the data is getting loaded with bad data then i would **strongly** suggest fixing it while you are importing the data.  Tim's answer will work for what you are doing but I strongly suspect you are coming at this wrong.  Iterrating through the whole database looking for potentially bad data is very inefficient.

Comment: I would agree with this approach much more than the answer I posted - if you know wrong data is being imported "at the first time," then you should be able to correct that on import, not later.

Answer (score 0):

If managed objects are getting created with the 'wrong data', I would check to make sure you've set default values in your model for all properties of all entities.  This way you can be sure whenever you insert an object into your context it will contain those values.  From there, you can set the properties to whatever you need.